# EKS 1.22 update - ingress and alb not working

Tags: updates, amazon-eks, deprecated, amazon-elb, ingress-controller

After updating EKS cluster to 1.22 all websites are down. Pods are ok but all the networking is not working.

[image]
I don't know how to fix ingresses and load balancer.

1. I have tried updating deprecated API versions for ingress-kong and internal-ingress-kong.
2. I can't find yaml file for alb-ingress-controller, but when I check last applied it is based on new API.
3. I have manually updated docker image of alb from 1.1.8 to 2.4.1

```html
Name:                   alb-ingress-controller
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 03 Sep 2020 02:05:01 +0000
Labels:                 app=alb-ingress-controller
                        app.kubernetes.io/name=alb-ingress-controller
                        git_version=54709a8bd94f795b1184b0c8336e9a6ec8aee807
                        name=alb-ingress-controller
                        version=20200909005829
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 9
Selector:               app.kubernetes.io/name=alb-ingress-controller
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=alb-ingress-controller
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=alb-ingress-controller
                    git_version=54709a8bd94f795b1184b0c8336e9a6ec8aee807
                    name=alb-ingress-controller
                    version=20200909005829
  Annotations:      kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2022-04-14T19:19:01Z
  Service Account:  alb-ingress-controller
  Containers:
   alb-ingress-controller:
    Image:      docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v2.4.1
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Args:
      --watch-namespace=default
      --ingress-class=alb-ingress-controller
      --cluster-name=staging-trn
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   alb-ingress-controller-c46ff7bd9 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

I'm new to kubernetes and aws.
**I think I have updated deprecated APIs in all places but errors are still pointing to the old APIs.**

Error on ingresses:

```
E0415 07:54:29.332371 1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource (get ingresses.extensions)
```

Error on alb:

```
{"level":"error","ts":1650009210.0149224,"logger":"setup","msg":"unable to create controller","controller":"TargetGroupBinding","error":"no matches for kind \"TargetGroupBinding\" in version \"elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1\""}
```

I have created missing CRD TargetGroupBindings:

```
    apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  annotations:
    controller-gen.kubebuilder.io/version: v0.5.0
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: targetgroupbindings.elbv2.k8s.aws
spec:
  group: elbv2.k8s.aws
  names:
    kind: TargetGroupBinding
    listKind: TargetGroupBindingList
    plural: targetgroupbindings
    singular: targetgroupbinding
  scope: Namespaced
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          description: TargetGroupBinding is the Schema for the TargetGroupBinding API
          properties:
            apiVersion:
              description: 'APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation
                of an object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest
                internal value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources'
              type: string
            kind:
              description: 'Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this
                object represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client
                submits requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds'
              type: string
            metadata:
              type: object
            spec:
              description: TargetGroupBindingSpec defines the desired state of TargetGroupBinding
              properties:
                networking:
                  description: networking provides the networking setup for ELBV2 LoadBalancer
                    to access targets in TargetGroup.
                  properties:
                    ingress:
                      description: List of ingress rules to allow ELBV2 LoadBalancer
                        to access targets in TargetGroup.
                      items:
                        properties:
                          from:
                            description: List of peers which should be able to access
                              the targets in TargetGroup. At least one NetworkingPeer
                              should be specified.
                            items:
                              description: NetworkingPeer defines the source/destination
                                peer for networking rules.
                              properties:
                                ipBlock:
                                  description: IPBlock defines an IPBlock peer. If specified,
                                    none of the other fields can be set.
                                  properties:
                                    cidr:
                                      description: CIDR is the network CIDR. Both IPV4
                                        or IPV6 CIDR are accepted.
                                      type: string
                                  required:
                                  - cidr
                                  type: object
                                securityGroup:
                                  description: SecurityGroup defines a SecurityGroup
                                    peer. If specified, none of the other fields can
                                    be set.
                                  properties:
                                    groupID:
                                      description: GroupID is the EC2 SecurityGroupID.
                                      type: string
                                  required:
                                  - groupID
                                  type: object
                              type: object
                            type: array
                          ports:
                            description: List of ports which should be made accessible
                              on the targets in TargetGroup. If ports is empty or unspecified,
                              it defaults to all ports with TCP.
                            items:
                              properties:
                                port:
                                  anyOf:
                                  - type: integer
                                  - type: string
                                  description: The port which traffic must match. When
                                    NodePort endpoints(instance TargetType) is used,
                                    this must be a numerical port. When Port endpoints(ip
                                    TargetType) is used, this can be either numerical
                                    or named port on pods. if port is unspecified, it
                                    defaults to all ports.
                                  x-kubernetes-int-or-string: true
                                protocol:
                                  description: The protocol which traffic must match.
                                    If protocol is unspecified, it defaults to TCP.
                                  enum:
                                  - TCP
                                  - UDP
                                  type: string
                              type: object
                            type: array
                        required:
                        - from
                        - ports
                        type: object
                      type: array
                  type: object
                serviceRef:
                  description: serviceRef is a reference to a Kubernetes Service and
                    ServicePort.
                  properties:
                    name:
                      description: Name is the name of the Service.
                      type: string
                    port:
                      anyOf:
                      - type: integer
                      - type: string
                      description: Port is the port of the ServicePort.
                      x-kubernetes-int-or-string: true
                  required:
                  - name
                  - port
                  type: object
                targetGroupARN:
                  description: targetGroupARN is the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for
                    the TargetGroup.
                  type: string
                targetType:
                  description: targetType is the TargetType of TargetGroup. If unspecified,
                    it will be automatically inferred.
                  enum:
                  - instance
                  - ip
                  type: string
              required:
              - serviceRef
              - targetGroupARN
              type: object
            status:
              description: TargetGroupBindingStatus defines the observed state of TargetGroupBinding
              properties:
                observedGeneration:
                  description: The generation observed by the TargetGroupBinding controller.
                  format: int64
                  type: integer
              type: object
          type: object
      additionalPrinterColumns:
      - jsonPath: .spec.serviceRef.name
        description: The Kubernetes Service's name
        name: SERVICE-NAME
        type: string
      - jsonPath: .spec.serviceRef.port
        description: The Kubernetes Service's port
        name: SERVICE-PORT
        type: string
      - jsonPath: .spec.targetType
        description: The AWS TargetGroup's TargetType
        name: TARGET-TYPE
        type: string
      - jsonPath: .spec.targetGroupARN
        description: The AWS TargetGroup's Amazon Resource Name
        name: ARN
        priority: 1
        type: string
      - jsonPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
        name: AGE
        type: date
```

Answer (score 0):

Ingress resource should be updated as follows:

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

pls see examples here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource

to find ingress resources type the following:
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces

then do the modification as mentioned above

pls be noted that backend configuration in ingress resource also needs some modification due to api change

also please be noted that from version 1.18 you're able to bind ingress resources using spec.ingressClassName field. If Omitted, ingress will work only if ingressClass that ingress controller implements is set to default.